# Automatically Carrying Out Commands When Opening Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

Is it possible to get a terminal to run a specific command (in my case "source /etc/environment") whenever I open the terminal? Thank you.

Comment: you should source /etc/environment be sourced before you run window manager, this way, terminal will inherit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

First, try:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

If there is any existing content, just go to the end of the file, otherwise it is a blank file. Either way, at the end of this file, add:

```
echo Hello Antoin, sourcing now ...

source /etc/environment
```

Save the file:

In nano:

1. exit by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
2. asks something about if you want to save, so <kbd>y</kbd>
3. it shows a file name to write, just <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm and exit

Run

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

On your screen you should see something like:

```
$ Hello Antoin, sourcing now ...
```

As well as whatever you expect to see when you normally `source /etc/environment`

This will now also happen whenever you open new terminals until you edit `~/.bashrc` again and follow these steps to save and reload these settings.

### Explanation

When you say

> whenever I open the terminal

I'm guessing it is the situation of a non-login interactive shell , when you are logged in to your machine, maybe in a GUI environment and are launching new terminals.

In that case, putting commands in `~/.bashrc` will cause it to be run whenever you open a new terminal.

We use `nano` because it is simple and installed by default on many distros, use another editor if you prefer eg `vim ~/.bashrc`

The tilde `~` is a shortcut for your `$HOME` variable. so if your username is `antoin` then if you test `echo ~/.bashrc` it should show: `/home/antoin/.bashrc` , the actual path to `.bashrc` file we need to edit.

We did `. ~/.bashrc` which is a shortcut for `source ~/.bashrc`.

The `echo Hello Antoin, sourcing now ...` line is optional, just a tracer to give us some feedback so if you don't even see this line, then something else is wrong or for some reason your system does not load `~.bashrc` and we will know a different answer is necessary for your situation.

### Further reading

More reading about the other kinds of shells eg login shells, what the differences are, the order that such configuration files are read: http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm completely new to using terminals so I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "edit ~/.bashrc"...
Also, it say "permission is denied" when I type "~/.bashrc" into the terminal... (Sorry I don't understand)

Comment: No problem, let me update my answer a little in a sec... re: denied, yes don't type just ~/.bashrc I get permission denied too , only because you dont directly refer to it that way.

Comment: @AntoinStanton what in the answer is meant is: use any plain text editor, (like `vi`, `nano`, `gedit`, etc.) that you wish/fancy, and edit/create the file `.bashrc` that is in your user's home folder (represented by `~`)

Comment: Thank you so much dave, I have it working now! Great help! Have a great day.